# Python Tkinter Notebook cover other component

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to use notebook of tkinter to creat tab, but i don't know why my notebook always cover other component(label、button、combbox),i find some articles say the pack() and grid () can't use together,so i just used grid() to draw component,but it still cover other component

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial
import sys;print(sys.path)

#變數
Scan_Com_Stop = 0

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Melexis MLX90397 Demo")
        window.minsize(width=500, height=500)
        window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.uartState = False # is uart open or not
        
        # a frame contains COM's information, and start/stop button
        #frame_Serial = tk.Frame(window)
        #frame_Memory = tk.Frame(window, bg='#09c')
        #frame_Serial.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        #frame_Memory.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        frame_COMinf= tk.Frame(window,relief='groove',bg='#7AFEC6')
        frame_COMinf.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        notebook=ttk.Notebook (window)
        
        #creat tab
        notebook.add(frame_COMinf, text="UART") 
        #notebook.add(frame_Memory, text="Memory") 
        notebook.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        # 標籤元件
        labelCOM = tk.Label(frame_COMinf,text="COMx: ")
        labelCOM.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.COM = tk.StringVar(value = "COM4")
        labelCOM.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 3)
        
        labelBaudrate = tk.Label(frame_COMinf,text="Baudrate: ")
        self.Baudrate = tk.StringVar(value ="9600")
        Baudrate_combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame_COMinf, width = 17,values=self.Baudrate)
        Baudrate_combobox["values"] = ("1200","2400","4800","9600","19200","38400")
        Baudrate_combobox["state"]="readonly"
        labelBaudrate.grid(row = 2, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 3)
        Baudrate_combobox.grid(row = 2, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 3)
        
        #下拉選單
        self.selected_port = tk.StringVar(value = "Select COM...")
        port_combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame_COMinf,textvariable=self.selected_port)
        port_combobox['values'] = [port.device for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()]
        port_combobox.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 3)
        
        #按鈕元件
        self.button = Button(frame_COMinf, text="Start", command=self.button_clicked)
        self.button.grid(row = 3, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 3, sticky = tk.E)
        
        # UART receiver
        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        # serial read threading
        self.ReadUARTThread = threading.Thread(target=self.ReadUART)
        self.ReadUARTThread.start()
        
        frameRecv = tk.Frame(window)
        frameRecv.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        labelOutText = tk.Label(frameRecv,text="Received Data:")
        labelOutText.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 3, pady = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        frameRecvSon = tk.Frame(frameRecv)
        frameRecvSon.grid(row = 2, column =1)
        scrollbarRecv = tk.Scrollbar(frameRecvSon)
        scrollbarRecv.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
        self.OutputText = tk.Text(frameRecvSon, wrap = tk.WORD, width = 60, height = 20, yscrollcommand = scrollbarRecv.set)
        self.OutputText.pack()
        
        frameTrans = tk.Frame(window)
        frameTrans.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        labelInText = tk.Label(frameTrans,text="To Transmit Data:")
        labelInText.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 3, pady = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        frameTransSon = tk.Frame(frameTrans)
        frameTransSon.grid(row = 2, column =1)
        scrollbarTrans = tk.Scrollbar(frameTransSon)
        scrollbarTrans.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
        self.InputText = tk.Text(frameTransSon, wrap = tk.WORD, width = 60, height = 5, yscrollcommand = scrollbarTrans.set)
        self.InputText.pack()
        self.buttonSend = tk.Button(frameTrans, text = "Send", command = self.processButtonSend)
        self.buttonSend.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 3, sticky = tk.E)
        
        #memory tab
        #self.bt=tk.Button (frame_Memory, text="Go", command=self.msg) 
        #self.bt.grid(row = 3, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 3, sticky = tk.E)
        
        window.mainloop()
    
    def msg():
        messagebox.showinfo("Go", "gogogo")
    def button_clicked(self):
        # print(self.Parity.get())
        if (self.uartState):
            self.ser.close()
            self.button["text"] = "Start"
            self.uartState = False
        else:
            # restart serial port
            self.ser.port = self.selected_port.get()
            self.ser.baudrate = self.Baudrate.get()
            self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE;
            self.ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE;
            """
            strParity = self.Parity.get()
            if (strParity=="NONE"):
                self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE;
            elif(strParity=="ODD"):
                self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_ODD;
            elif(strParity=="EVEN"):
                self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN;
            elif(strParity=="MARK"):
                self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_MARK;
            elif(strParity=="SPACE"):
                self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_SPACE;
            
                
            strStopbits = self.Stopbits.get()
            if (strStopbits == "1"):
                self.ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE;
            elif (strStopbits == "1.5"):
                self.ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE_POINT_FIVE;
            elif (strStopbits == "2"):
                self.ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_TWO;
            """
            self.ser.open()
            if (self.ser.isOpen()): # open success
                self.button["text"] = "Stop"
                self.uartState = True
        
    def processButtonSend(self):
        if (self.uartState):
            strToSend = self.InputText.get(1.0,tk.END)
            bytesToSend = strToSend[0:-1].encode(encoding='ascii')
            self.ser.write(bytesToSend)
            print(bytesToSend)
        else:
            print("Not In Connect!")
    def ReadUART(self):
        # print("Threading...")
        while True:
            if (self.uartState):
                try:
                    ch = self.ser.read().decode(encoding='ascii')
                    print(ch,end='')
                    self.OutputText.insert(tk.END,ch)
                except:
                    print("Something wrong in receiving.")

GUI()
```

Colud you tell me,How do i modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

You create the `frame_COMinf` widget that is to be the notebook page with the main window as it's parent.  As this is done before creating the notebook which has the same parent the frame is lower in the z-order than the notebook. You can fix this by calling `frame_COMinf.tkraise()` to bring it to the top of the z-order.

However the correct fix is to make the parent of the frames you use in the notebook be the notebook. Something like the following example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
page1 = tk.Frame(notebook, background="red", width=240, height=400)
page2 = tk.Frame(notebook, background="green", width=240, height=400)
notebook.add(page1, text="Page 1")
notebook.add(page2, text="Page 2")
notebook.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes,you are correct , i already try to scessful, but i have another issue, when i  make the parent of the frames in the notebook, how to arrange other frames by calling  `grid(row, column)` ?

Comment: The notebook is a geometry manager that manages the geometry of a set of widgets by showing one at a time. The frames that you add to the notebook should not also be managed by another geometry manager (ie: do not try and pack, grid or place them). The `winfo_manager` method of a widget returns its manager - in this case 'notebook'. When the notebook tab is clicked it then shows the relevant managed widget for that notebook page and hides the other managed widgets.

Comment: Thank you for your info, Could you give me sample for how do arrange component in notebook ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i suddenly understand why my component are covering each other,beacsuse i use wrong grid(row,column) in same frame

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial
import sys;print(sys.path)

#變數
Scan_Com_Stop = 0

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Melexis MLX90397 Demo" )
        window.minsize(width=500, height=500)
        window.configure(bg="#4F4F4F")
        window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.uartState = False # is uart open or not
        
        # a frame contains COM's information, and start/stop button
        notebook=ttk.Notebook (window)
        frame_uart_notebook = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='#02DF82')
        frame_mem_notebook = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='#81C0C0')
        
        frame_COMinf= tk.Frame(frame_uart_notebook, bg='#9F0050')
        frame_Memory = tk.Frame(frame_mem_notebook, bg='#2894FF')
        frame_COMinf.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        #creat tab
        notebook.add(frame_uart_notebook, text="UART") 
        notebook.add(frame_mem_notebook, text="Memory") 
        notebook.pack (padx=10, pady=10, fill='both', expand=True)
        # 標籤元件
        labelCOM = tk.Label(frame_COMinf,text="COMx: ")
        labelCOM.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 3)
        
        #下拉選單
        self.selected_port = tk.StringVar(value = "Select COM...")
        port_combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame_COMinf,textvariable=self.selected_port)
        port_combobox['values'] = [port.device for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()]
        port_combobox.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 3)
        
        labelBaudrate = tk.Label(frame_COMinf,text="Baudrate: ")
        self.Baudrate = tk.StringVar(value ="9600")
        Baudrate_combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame_COMinf, width = 17,values=self.Baudrate)
        Baudrate_combobox["values"] = ("1200","2400","4800","9600","19200","38400")
        Baudrate_combobox["state"]="readonly"
        labelBaudrate.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 3)
        Baudrate_combobox.grid(row = 1, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 3)
        
        #按鈕元件
        self.button = Button(frame_COMinf, text="Start", command=self.button_clicked)
        self.button.grid(row = 2, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 3, sticky = tk.E)
        
        # UART receiver
        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        # serial read threading
        self.ReadUARTThread = threading.Thread(target=self.ReadUART)
        self.ReadUARTThread.start()
        
        
        frameRecv = tk.Frame(frame_uart_notebook,bg='#82D900')
        frameRecv.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        labelOutText = tk.Label(frameRecv,text="Received Data:")
        labelOutText.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 3, pady = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        frameRecvSon = tk.Frame(frameRecv,bg='#FFA042')
        frameRecvSon.grid(row = 2, column =1)
        scrollbarRecv = tk.Scrollbar(frameRecvSon)
        scrollbarRecv.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
        self.OutputText = tk.Text(frameRecvSon, wrap = tk.WORD, width = 60, height = 20, yscrollcommand = scrollbarRecv.set)
        self.OutputText.pack()
        
        
        frameTrans = tk.Frame(frame_uart_notebook)
        frameTrans.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        labelInText = tk.Label(frameTrans,text="To Transmit Data:")
        labelInText.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 3, pady = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        frameTransSon = tk.Frame(frameTrans)
        frameTransSon.grid(row = 2, column =1)
        scrollbarTrans = tk.Scrollbar(frameTransSon)
        scrollbarTrans.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
        self.InputText = tk.Text(frameTransSon, wrap = tk.WORD, width = 60, height = 5, yscrollcommand = scrollbarTrans.set)
        self.InputText.pack()
        self.buttonSend = tk.Button(frameTrans, text = "Send", command = self.processButtonSend)
        self.buttonSend.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 3, sticky = tk.E)
        
        #memory tab
        #self.bt=tk.Button (frame_Memory, text="Go", command=self.msg) 
        #self.bt.grid(row = 3, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 3, sticky = tk.E)
        
        window.mainloop()
    
    def msg():
        messagebox.showinfo("Go", "gogogo")
    def button_clicked(self):
        # print(self.Parity.get())
        if (self.uartState):
            self.ser.close()
            self.button["text"] = "Start"
            self.uartState = False
        else:
            # restart serial port
            self.ser.port = self.selected_port.get()
            self.ser.baudrate = self.Baudrate.get()
            self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE;
            self.ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE;
            self.ser.open()
            if (self.ser.isOpen()): # open success
                self.button["text"] = "Stop"
                self.uartState = True
        
    def processButtonSend(self):
        if (self.uartState):
            strToSend = self.InputText.get(1.0,tk.END)
            bytesToSend = strToSend[0:-1].encode(encoding='ascii')
            self.ser.write(bytesToSend)
            print(bytesToSend)
        else:
            print("Not In Connect!")
    def ReadUART(self):
        # print("Threading...")
        while True:
            if (self.uartState):
                try:
                    ch = self.ser.read().decode(encoding='ascii')
                    print(ch,end='')
                    self.OutputText.insert(tk.END,ch)
                except:
                    print("Something wrong in receiving.")

GUI()
```